# c# excel interop Click on button

Tags: c#, excel, interop

i want click on button in [excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APbKS.png) with "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel".
with following code just do select cell but Not clicked

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook book = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.ActiveSheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ExcelRange = sheet.get_Range("A4");
        ExcelRange.Select();
```

How to click button?

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, I will need to get clarification from you through the answer. Are you attempting to run a macro with the button click?

If so, the direction should be accessing the data itself or the macro itself.

For accessing Excel Data, you can refer to:

[Read Data from Excel using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793442/how-to-read-data-from-excel-file-using-c-sharp)

For accessing Excel Macro, you can refer to:

[Running Excel Macro using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248592/running-an-excel-macro-via-c-run-a-macro-from-one-workbook-on-another)

Comment: I don't have the password macro for the Excel file, so I have to enter it manually

Comment: You can specify the password parameter in Workbooks.Open. The documentation can be refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open?view=excel-pia