# Automate Excel from Visual Studio

Tags: excel

How can I automate Excel so that I do not need to work with the VBA editor inside Excel? I want to click a button in Excel and execute some code. This code applies changes to multiple cells in the Excel sheets. How Do I do this from Visual Studio with C#?

I know that I can control Excel with COM Interop, but if I want to call a method that is linked to a button inside the Excel sheet, how do I realize this in my external c# application? Here is my code for testing purposes; I cannot get this working. This is my Excel VBA code:

```
Sub clickbutton()

  Dim mObj As Object
  Set mObj = New ClassEx()
  MsgBox mObj.Push()
End Sub
```

In Excel I did add the DLL via "Extras > References". Strangely, in Excel (when I open the object browser) I can only see the ClassEx entry, but no methods at all! This is my C# code that yields the DLL:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ExLib
{
  public class ClassEx
  {
    public ClassEx() 
    { 

    }

    public double Push()
    {
        return 5.0;
    }
  }
}
```

In VS I did set the build target to x64 for my 64 bit excel, I did set COM visbility to on and I set Register for COM Interop to on.

But I get errors when getting to the line `Set mObj = ClassEx()` stating that the method is not defined. When I call my dll from a totally different project written in C#, everything work; I just cannot call my DLL from Excel. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running an Excel Macro via C#: Run a macro from one workbook on another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248592/running-an-excel-macro-via-c-run-a-macro-from-one-workbook-on-another)

Comment: No, I dont think this answer the question. I am specifically interested in how to call a method in my c# project from excel.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Despite using Excel 2019, it is a 32 Bit application. Now it works when compiling the DLL for 32 bit.